# How can I re-hide previously hidden files?

Tags: windows, command-line

Previously I used `attrib -s -h -r /s /d` to un-hide all hidden files in `D:\`.
How can I re-hide the previously hidden files that are hidden by default? Most of them are `desktop.ini` and `Thumbs.db`

Comment: You didn't use `Attrib +h +s +r` to show them. You used it to assign the `hidden`, `system`, and `read-only` attributes to them. Have a look at [TechNet - Attrib](https://technet.microsoft.com/de-de/library/bb490868.aspx) for reference. Please correct your question, it's unclear / misleadingly. Thanks.

Comment: I have just edited my question. What I want is to hide the previously hidden files that are hidden by default.

Comment: @NetworkKingPin That will assign those attributes to ALL files on that drive, not just the ones previously hidden.

Comment: Removed Comment thank you @CharlieRB The question was still unclear as to what exactly he did.

Comment: We are assuming by the existence of `thumbs.db` that you are using Windows. Please let us know which version of Windows you are using and what you have tried. It is likely we can not help you because we have no idea what all files were hidden. And not that you have changed the attributes, neither does your file system.

Comment: Sorry for my stupid question. I have already fixed the problem simply by deleting those files one by one manually.  All those previously hidden files are actually unneeded.

Comment: @ Clijsters, I have changed `Attrib +h +s +r` to `attrib -s -h -r /s /d`. I copied the wrong command.

Answer (score 2):

You could make use of windows built in GUI for showing hidden files and folders.

Open Control Panel > click Appearance and Personalization > click Folder Options.

Click the View tab.

Under Advanced settings, click Show hidden files, folders, and drives.

Check/Uncheck the various options to hide/show files with the hidden attribute

Comment: this answer is great, but it seems that it doesn't answer "how can I **hide** previously hidden files". ..And I guess he means the file attributes itself.

Comment: @Clijsters I know what you mean. I couldn't comment yet, so I tried to leave an answer that may or may not be useful.  Technically it does tell a user how to hide/show previously hidden files. But you are right in that, it does not specify how to modify the hidden attribute of files (which is probably what he meant)

Comment: I think without additional Information from the questioner, it's the most useful thing, some could do. Theoretically we don't even know his Operating System.

Comment: I have just edited my question. What I want is to hide the previously hidden files that are hidden by default.

Comment: This will only work if the file attributes are set correctly. If they are not set to `hidden`, this will not hide them. We really need more information from the OP to be able to answer.

Comment: Sorry for my stupid question. I have already fixed the problem simply by deleting those files one by one manually.  All those previously hidden files are actually unneeded.

Answer (score 1):

At drive root, `cmd`:

```
attrib +s +h -r Desktop.ini /s
attrib +s +h -r Thumbs.db /s
```

These commands reset attributes for all `Desktop.ini` and `Thumbs.db` in a target drive you run the command from.

Be aware that it could take a while.

It only resets file properties but will not change your Explorer settings. Hidden system files are hidden by default but can be changed to always show by user.